# Inheritance and forcing methods to be called inside another method

Tags: python, inheritance

I've written a text parser that extracts useful information from a given text. Texts are formatted different, so there are different specialized parsers. I've designed them so that they all must define the methods from the interface Parser.

```
class Parser:
    def parse(text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def pre_validate(text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def post_validate():
        raise NotImplementedError
```

How can I force all subclasses of Parser to call pre_validate before running parse and post_validate after calling parse?

I could solve it like this, but I don't think it's very elegant to wrap methods like this:

```
class Parser:       
    def parse(text):
        self.pre_validate(text)
        self._parse()
        self.post_validate(text)

    def _parse(text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def pre_validate(text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def post_validate():
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Ideally I'd like to allow the subclasses to implement the method `parse` instead of `_parse`. What's the recommended way of solving this? Would it make sense to use a python decorator here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix the issue by making parser a collection of callables, rather than a class with fixed methods. This would be handy for other aspects of this kind of parsing, so you could easily reuse pre-parsing and post-parsing functions that might be more similar than the parsing:

```
class ParseOperation(object):

    def __init__(self, pre_validator, parser, post_validator):
       self.pre_validator = pre_validator
       self.parser= parser
       self.post_validator= post_validator

   def parse(self, text):
      self.pre_validator(self, text)
      self.parser(self, text)
      self.post_validator(self, text)

class Validator(object):

   def validate(self, owner, text):
     print 'validating %s' % text

   def __call__(self, owner, text):
     self.validate(owner, text)

class Parser (object):
   def parse(self, owner, text):
      print 'parsing %s' % text

   def __call__(self, owner, text):
     self.parse(owner, text)
```

Instead of overriding methods, you subclass Parser and Validator to compose your parse operation.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that like this:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parse = self._validated_parsing(self.parse)

    def parse(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def pre_validate(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def post_validate(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _validated_parsing(self, parse_func):
        def parse_wrapper(text):
            self.pre_validate(text)
            parse_func(text)
            self.post_validate(text)
        return parse_wrapper

class ParserChild(Parser):
    def parse(self, text):
        print('parsing')

    def pre_validate(self, text):
        print('pre-validating')

    def post_validate(self, text):
        print('post-validating')

ParserChild().parse('spam')
# pre-validating
# parsing
# post-validating
```

I recommend doing it with an extra method that is called from `parse` though, like the `_parse` method you wrote.  It should not be called directly from outside, so it should be written with a leading underscore.  You might want to want to call it something more explicit, such as (in lack of a better name) `_core_parse`.

While we're at it, maybe `pre_validate` and `post_validate` should be preceded with an underscore too (depending on whether you want them to be called from outside the class).

Instead of raising `NotImplementedError` in the base class, you should use [`abc.ABCMeta`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) for an abstract base class.  This is better for two reasons:

- You can't create a subclass that doesn't implement all abstract methods.
- It will work together properly with the [`super`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) function which delegates calls to superclasses (base classes).

So, I think I would implement the class like this:

```
import abc

class Parser(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def parse(self, text):
        self._pre_validate(text)
        self._core_parse(text)
        self._post_validate(text)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _pre_validate(self, text):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _core_parse(self, text):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _post_validate(self, text):
        pass

class ParserChild(Parser):
    def _core_parse(self, text):
        print('parsing')

    def _pre_validate(self, text):
        print('pre-validating')

    def _post_validate(self, text):
        print('post-validating')

ParserChild().parse('spamspam')
# pre-validating
# parsing
# post-validating
```

(I'm assuming you use Python 3, but if you're using Python 2, you should let `Parser` inherit from `object`. In Python 3, this happens automatically.)